# Google Tag Manager (Firebase) error when logging event

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have integrated google tag manager and firebase into my iOS project.  When I log an event they appear in the firebase console, but with the google tag Manager i keep getting this error

```
GoogleTagManager error: Error executing tag 1: Attempting to assign to undefined value 30,15,b,39,2,17,15,gtmUtils,common,isArray,7,15,a,7,8
```

Which means the events don't appear in google analytics.

I have removed all of my tags, triggers and no matter how they are set up this error always appears.

Anyone seen this error before?